# CreateAnonymousThread with parameters

Tags: delphi

In C# we have `ParameterizedThreadStart` that allows us to create a thread passing parameters to it, like so:

```
Thread thread = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(fetchURL));
thread.Start(url);

// ...
static void fetchURL(object url)
{
    // ...
}
```

I tried to reproduce on Delphi using `CreateAnonymousThread` but it seems that it does not accept arguments.

How can I create an anonymous thread and pass argument to the called procedure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[TThread.CreateAnonymousThread](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread) takes an [anonymous method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Anonymous_Methods_in_Delphi) as a parameter so you can put together a method that passes in any values that you would like. These values are captured so you will need to be careful when passing in the parameters. Read the "Variable Binding Mechanism" section in the anonymous method link above for more information about variable capture.

For example:

```
procedure DoSomething(const aWebAddress: String);
begin
end;

procedure BuildThread;
var
  myThread: TThread;
  fetchURL: string;
begin
  fetchURL := 'http://stackoverflow.com';
  // Create an anonymous thread that calls a method and passes in
  // the fetchURL to that method.
  myThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      DoSomething(fetchURL);
    end);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: may I suggest that a local variable be made and `1` was assigned to the local variable instead of being a constant, so it was really a parameter. Now it is not, it is just compiled into the code. Just like `DoSomething` - it is a constant address of procedure, not a variable, thus is not "passed". Same holds for `1`, it is NOT  a parameter now.

Comment: @Arioch'The I can do that. The example was the simplest I could put together that demonstrated the OP's requirement which was passing a parameter into the method. I could just as easily put together a compiler that created an internal variable and passed that it. My understanding of the OP's requirement was that he/she wanted to be able to pass something into the anonymous thread. It could be a constant or a variable.

Comment: `pass something into the anonymous thread` - true, but you only can `pas` something that does not already belong there, right? When you have a variable in procedure 1 you can `pass` it to procedure 2. but if you have a variable in procedure 2 then procedure 1 can not pass it to procedure 2 - t is already there! Your initial code had the constant declared - thus belonging to - the anonymous procedure right out. Now with the string var declared - thus belonging to - the outer procedure you really do capture and pass it.

Comment: @Graymatter is this completly thread safe !? i mean if i call this 4 time it make 4 new threads!?

Comment: @peimanF. That's correct. There is no interaction between the threads. If your threads are sharing objects then that's a different matter and you would need to deal with that.